# Lenovo Y520 Freeze when updating

Tags: updates, lenovo, freeze

I read so many posts in this forum but no problem is similar to mine. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo Legion Y520, I put it in the SSD while the HDD keeps Windows 10. Whenever I launch Ubuntu it goes extremely slow and it freezes almost immediately. I can't install updates, I can't do anything. I read of installing Nvidia drivers but I can't reach this step. I already removed secure boot.
If someone knows the solution, please help me.

Comment: Yes, you need Nvidia proprietary drivers and to do that in some cases you need to boot with the `nomodeset` parameter otherwise it will freeze or not boot a GUI at all. https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/

Comment: After I use the nomodeset boot version how can I get the drivers?

Comment: Didn't you *read of installing Nvidia drivers but I can't reach this step*? Well, now you can. It's as simple as opening "Software & Updates", then the "Additional Drivers" tab, select and apply the recommended version, reboot.